# Python/Beautiful soup find_all() doesn't find all

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I use `find_all()` I should get 100 results but I only get 25.

**CODE**

Here is the code where i crawl [tweakers](https://tweakers.net/categorie/545/geheugen-intern/producten/) and try to return each  element where the class is equal to largethumb.

Once i've done that I filter out the name and price.

```
my_url = 'https://tweakers.net/categorie/545/geheugen-intern/producten/'
uReq(my_url)
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#should be 100 tr object's
products = page_soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "largethumb"})
for product in products:
    title = product.p.text
    price_container = product.find_all("p", {"class": "price"})
    price = price_container[0].text
    lijst = title, price
    print(lijst)
```

**RESULT**

The result is 25 times this.

```
('Corsair Vengeance LPX CMK16GX4M2B3000C15', '€ 174,90')
```

Comment: `i should get 100 resuts but i only get 25` Why do you expect to get 100 if clearly the page only displays 25 elements by default? Your code doesn't select to display 100 results per page.

Comment: Can you add the imports to your code? You seem to have renamed `urlopen` to `uReq` for some reason.

Comment: It looks like this website stores the pagination size in a cookie - try opening it in a private window to see that the "default" configuration is in fact 25.

Answer (score 1):

The website in question by default displays 25 search results. If it is different in your web browser, that's because of cookies your browser has from the site in question. If you want to get 100 results, edit `my_url` like so:

```
my_url = 'https://tweakers.net/categorie/545/geheugen-intern/producten/?pageSize=100&page=1'
uReq(my_url)
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# WILL be 100 tr object's
products = page_soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "largethumb"})
for product in products:
    title = product.p.text
    price_container = product.find_all("p", {"class": "price"})
    price = price_container[0].text
    lijst = title, price
    print(lijst)
```

Proof it works:

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> my_url = 'https://tweakers.net/categorie/545/geheugen-
intern/producten/?pageSize=100&page=1'
>>> r = get(my_url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
>>> len(soup.find_all('tr', attrs={"class": "largethumb"}))
100
```

If you hover over the 100 results button in the bottom left hand corner, you see this url is what they redirect you to. Happy scraping!

Answer (score 1):

Give it a go. It will fetch you all the 25 results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res =requests.get('https://tweakers.net/categorie/545/geheugen-intern/producten/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for product in soup.find_all(class_="largethumb"):
    title = product.find_all(class_="editionName")[0]['title']
    price = product.find_all(class_="price")[0].text
    print(title,price)
```

Btw, the link you provided displays 25 results in each page.